# How to troubleshoot code when it is printing entire column file as opposed to line being searched for? perl

Tags: perl, count, counter

I have been working on this code for a few days and am having an issue in the final leg. The goal is to have the file print out the amount of times a "disease/trait" appears in a file., using a counter The issue is that the code simply prints out everything in the one column of the array, as opposed to the amount of times it was searched for. I'm assuming this is an issue with the counter half of the code.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %TRAIThash;
my $usrin = "Leoprsy";
my %DISEASEslashTRAIT;   
open (my $input, "<", "gwas_catalog_v1.0-downloaded_2015-07-08.test") || die();

while (<$input>) {
    my @t = split (/\t/);
        my $tempVar = $t[7];
        chomp($tempVar);
        if (exists $DISEASEslashTRAIT{$tempVar}) {
            $DISEASEslashTRAIT{$tempVar}++;
    }
        else  {
            $DISEASEslashTRAIT{$tempVar}=1;
    }
}

my $DISEASEslashTRAITcount;
print $DISEASEslashTRAIT{"$usrin"}; "\n";
if (exists $DISEASEslashTRAIT{$usrin}) {
    print "\n $usrin is published ".$DISEASEslashTRAIT{$usrin}." times within the gwas database.\n";
}   
else {
    print "$usrin doesn't exist in the hash\n";
    }
close ($input);
```

what I would like it to print is "Maximal oxygen uptake response" is published X times within file."

I have looked through here and a few websites, but nothing has really worked when I have tried it. This has happened to me before so I would assume it is a common problem for those learning to code, but when this has happened I usually go back to the drawing board, so I'd like to find a way to solve this more simply. 
The input is a 33 column code, and I am using a 10 line test file. I cannot copy it in, but it is the GWAS data file. I have added strict and warnings and it now runs, with the exact same problem

Comment: You should *always* begin a Perl program with `use strict` and `use warnings`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and to the perl tag. You should start by adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to your program and declaring all your variables with `my $foo`. Then a word on naming variables: in Perl it is best practice to have lowercase variable names that use underscores. CAPS-ONLY variables should only be used for globals. Try to use speaking names for stuff. There are a few more conventions, like using `$fh` for a filehandle (if there is only one) and `$i` as a loop iterator. That said, please indent your code properly and [edit] your question.

Comment: I will edit this code to include that, but why exactly should I @Borodin

Comment: Also please include sample input. And see my comment for an answer to your question regarding @borodin's comment.

Comment: After taking a closer look at the code... **please do post example input**. There are some issues with your code that I can't fix simply because I don't understand what you are trying to do. I'm currently just trying to make it compile with `strict` and `warnings` but that's kinda hard.

Comment: @Michaela: Please see my answer below

Comment: When we say "programs should include `strict` and `warnings`" that also means "and the code should compile and run when you have". Whilst editing them in is nice, what you need do next is actually make your program work, and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

The `use strict` and `use warnings` pragmas provide a lot of information and assistance with writing clean code. Most importantly, you are required to declare all of your variables with `my` before you use them. That will pick up misspellings of identifiers

For instance, your first loop builds the `%DISEASEslashTRAIThash` hash, but in your second loop you are using `%DISEASEslashTRAIT`. You also have `exists $$DISEASEslashTRAIT{"$usrin"}` which should have just a single dollar sign, and `warnings` would have picked that up

Here's how I would write your program. It is best to avoid capitals in local variables

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in_fh, '<', 'file.test' or die $!;
my %disease_traits;
while ( <$in_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    my $disease_trait = (split /\t/)[7];
    ++$disease_traits{$disease_trait} if $disease_trait;
}

while () {
    my $usrin = "Maximal oxygen uptake response";
    # my $usrin = <>;
    chomp $usrin;
    my $count = $disease_traits{$usrin};
    if ( defined $count ) {
        print qq{\n "$usrin" is published $disease_traits{$usrin} times within file.\n};
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: That runs perfectly thank you thank you thank you @Borodin

Comment: If you have the time @Borodin , could you explain how your code works, and why it is superior to mine, so I can learn and become better?

Comment: @Michaela: Sure. I'll write some notes for you tomorrow